# Strip off seconds from joda DateTime java

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I have an `org.joda.time.DateTime` object, its timezone is "Asia/Shanghai" (i.e. +08:00), the date time value of it is "2021-06-22T22:30:**25**+08:00". I want to strip off seconds from it **without changing its original timezone**. The expected value is "2021-06-22T22:30:**00**+08:00". How can I do the strip?

Comment: If you think your own answer most accurately describes what helped you, feel free to accept it (you can change which answer to accept at any time, only I don’t think you can accept your own answer until 12 hours after it was posted, which have elapsed now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jodatime? It's 2021. Just use `java.time`. Which is jodatime with a few slight updates, and baked into the core java libraries.

At any rate, whether we're talking about jodatime or java.time, the data sturctures are immutable so what you want is impossible. You can't strip anything off. What you can do, is make new DateTime objects.

`myOriginalObject.withSecondsOfMinute(0)` does the job. Returns a new DT instance that has `00` for seconds.

Comment: java.time is a good idea. Unless you positively want to keep any fraction of second that might be there, I would prefer `myOriginalObject.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Shanghai");
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2021, 6, 22, 22, 30, 25, zone);

    dt = dt.withMillisOfSecond(0).withSecondOfMinute(0);
    
    System.out.println(dt);
    System.out.println("Is time zone changed? It is now " + dt.getZone());
```

Output:

> ```
> 2021-06-22T22:30:00.000+08:00
> Is time zone changed? It is now Asia/Shanghai
> ```

Bonus quote: The Joda-Time home page says:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
> No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
> to `java.time` (JSR-310).

Link: [Joda-Time home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Ole V.V. and rzwitserloot's answers, the following solved my problem

```
dateTime = new DateTime(dateTime).withMillisOfSecond(0).withSecondOfMinute(0);
```

(Type of `dateTime` is `org.joda.time.DateTime`)

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. You don’t need `new`, and it hardly brings you anything.